# Android: ImageView and ButtonView error object declaration

Tags: android, object

I have a problem in where i can declare the ImageView and ButtonView object:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_partita);
}
public int cont = 0;
int sceltaG1 = 0;
int sceltaPc = 0;

ImageButton G1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.g1view);
ImageView Pc = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pcview);
ImageButton VS = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.vsview);

public void giocoG1()
{
    if (sceltaG1==0) G1.setImageResource(R.drawable.sasso_logo);
    if (sceltaG1==1) G1.setImageResource(R.drawable.carta_logo);
    if (sceltaG1==2) G1.setImageResource(R.drawable.forbici_logo);

}
public void giocoPc()
{
    sceltaPc = (int) (Math.random()*3);
    if (sceltaPc==0) Pc.setImageResource(R.drawable.sasso_logo);
    if (sceltaPc==1) Pc.setImageResource(R.drawable.carta_logo);
    if (sceltaPc==2) Pc.setImageResource(R.drawable.forbici_logo);
}
public void cambioScelta()
{
    if (sceltaG1==2) sceltaG1 = 0;
    else sceltaG1++;
    giocoG1();
}
```

giocoG1(),giocoPc() and sceltaGicoO() are the onClick of 3 buttons where i have no problems.

But when i start the app (with not syntax errors) and i go in this actvity, the app do a "bad close". I discovered that  the problem are these object declarations:

```
ImageButton G1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.g1view);
ImageView Pc = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pcview);
ImageButton VS = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.vsview);
```

I tried to insert them in the onCreate funnction and they not give problems, but the functions below don't see the objects.
How can i solve? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the object references outside any method and initialize them in `onCreate()` method .

```
private ImageButton G1;
private ImageView Pc;
private ImageButton VS;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_partita);

    G1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.g1view);
    Pc = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pcview);
    VS = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.vsview);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you would define the ImageButtons and the ImageView just below your int-Variabes, but not assigning a value. Then, in the onCreate() you have to do the findViewById.

Cheers